# top rubyonrails screencast/tutorials/blog url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

i am learning rubyonrails and referring http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ for documentations and http://railscasts.com/ for screencast. Are there more such useful sites that could help me to learn more on rubyonrails?

Answer (score 7):

Here are some urls...

- http://rubyonrails.org/
- http://asciicasts.com/
- http://rails-bestpractices.com/
- http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-on-rails-uk
- http://rubyreflector.com/
- http://ruby.railstutorial.org/
- http://www.rubyinside.com/
- http://rubyquicktips.com/
- http://www.therailsway.com/
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: New kid on the block (2020) - https://www.semicolonandsons.com/series/Inside-The-Muse The focus is on a production codebase with 200k monthly sessions, real money flowing through, 10 years of legacy, and all the issues that accompany these complications.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the tutorial and screencast sites around, I learned a lot by looking at other people's sourcecode of productive applications.

For example, [Railscasts.com](http://Railscasts.com) by Ryan Bates [is open source](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts). Further than that, there is a large collection of open source rails sites at [opensourcerails.com](http://opensourcerails.com), [which itself is open source](https://github.com/jcnetdev/opensourcerails) (and really helpful).

The similar structure of all rails applications makes it easy to understand the code - and in my opinion, it's great to see how the experts link their models and build up their application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are completely new to Ruby on Rails, I strongly recommend you to diligently go through the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) by Michael Hartl (that is available free online) and if you have the cash, spend it on the excellent screen-casts. I found his text and the screencasts to be very approachable and easily understood.

I myself have bought them and found them to be an excellent resource. (Even better than [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) in my opinion)

Only once you have understood the basics should you then consult the API as you have listed in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

[Code School](http://www.codeschool.com/) is worth checking out.  Their Rails For Zombies course is free and a great place to start learning rails. If you like their style they offer advanced rails courses. For $25 a month you get access to all of their courses.